# C++ Pointer at array is printing values way past the array size

Tags: c++, arrays

I am planning on turning this code into a quick sort application, but I am using arrays, something I have not done since discovering vectors and becoming very spoiled with them. This leads me to this code.

```
int main() {


    int numbers[] = { 6, 5, 1, 3, 8, 4, 7, 9, 2};
    int* pivot; // will be used later when I implement quicksorting
    int currentElement = numbers[0]; //will be used for quicksorting
    std::cout<< "\n" << currentElement << "\n" << std::endl;
    int *ptr = numbers;

    for(int x = 0; x < sizeof(numbers); x++)
    {
        std::cout << "value at index: - " << x << " is: " << *(ptr + x) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am receiving this output.

```
5

value at index: - 0 is: 6
value at index: - 1 is: 5
value at index: - 2 is: 1
value at index: - 3 is: 3
value at index: - 4 is: 8
value at index: - 5 is: 4
value at index: - 6 is: 7
value at index: - 7 is: 9
value at index: - 8 is: 2
value at index: - 9 is: -858993460
value at index: - 10 is: 1211635769
value at index: - 11 is: 5241484
value at index: - 12 is: 12658446
value at index: - 13 is: 1
value at index: - 14 is: 6877496
value at index: - 15 is: 6875200
value at index: - 16 is: 5241572
value at index: - 17 is: 12658033
value at index: - 18 is: 1211635877
value at index: - 19 is: 12652609
value at index: - 20 is: 12652609
value at index: - 21 is: 4116480
value at index: - 22 is: 0
value at index: - 23 is: 0
value at index: - 24 is: 0
value at index: - 25 is: 0
value at index: - 26 is: 0
value at index: - 27 is: 0
value at index: - 28 is: 0
value at index: - 29 is: 12694900
value at index: - 30 is: 12694912
value at index: - 31 is: 0
value at index: - 32 is: 5241492
value at index: - 33 is: 0
value at index: - 34 is: 5241664
value at index: - 35 is: 12665872
```

Process finished with exit code `0`

The main question I have is why am I getting values in indexes past `index 8`? (`value 2`)

How do those even exist? Is this because the declaration I made at int `numbers[]` does not have a specified array size? The reason why I have that in the first place is I intend to populate the array with a random number generator with my quick sort algorithm, essentially treating the array like a vector. I know that this is illegal, but I am simply trying to relearn arrays, so I can be comfortable in other languages with them, as vectors do not exist in many others.

Am I getting these phantom indexes because the array allocation has a default block of memory that it takes if an array size is not specified, or is that already implicitly defined with the manual population of the array that I did with the values supplied in the curly braces and maybe that is causing the pointer to continue?

Comment: *I am hoping this is not a duplicated question* Duplicated questions doesn't cause any harm, they add more pointers to a common problem.

Comment: `sizeof(numbers)` gives the size of the array in bytes, not the number of elements in the array. And once you read past the end of an array, all bet are off.

Comment: Beta is correct. The number of items is determined with `sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0])`. That's a common error, unfortunately. Even the best will do it once in a while.

Comment: "Is this because the declaration I made at int numbers[] does not have a specified array size?". No. You are safe here. `int numbers[] = { 6, 5, 1, 3, 8, 4, 7, 9, 2};` sizes itself appropriately for the number of element in the initializer and knows how big it is. You could use a range-based `for` loop here (`for(auto x: numbers) std::cout << x  << std::endl;`)and avoid the headache.

Comment: I should also mention that my very first programming language was Java, which had arrays that did not allow me to go out of bounds like this one does. I was aware that C++ allows this, but I did not know to what extent, now I do I suppose, but based on the link [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why Should I be instead just sticking with vectors in C++ simply because they are dynamic in this situation?

Comment: You can go out of bounds on a `vector` as well. `operator[]` is unchecked, but the `at` method will throw an exception. Also look into `std::array` which has most of the `vector` gooddies, but isn't resizable. Depending on your insertion and removal pattern `std::deque` is often handy. C++ gives a lot of container options, so familiarize yourself with them and pick the one that best fits the task at hand.